# setting up asp application on hosting provider changing

Tags: sql-server, windows, iis, asp-classic, installation

i have never worked on windows iis, asp and mssql but now i am forced to do so.

the plot:

i have an asp mvc application (the exact folder tree copied from the old disabled server) and an mssql backup file (.bak). I have managed to restore the database and i have copied my application folder to httpdocs. BUT still...when i try to access the server it pops lots of errors. i know, lack of knowledge and app setup.

my question, in what order should i start setting up my app (what files, what settings..etc for a complete windows noob); i have no start point, i'm confused, put me on the track please. Any advice will be appreciated, any reference.

Keep in mind that i have advanced knowledge in apache server, php, mysql, html, css, javascript BUT ABSOLUTE ZERO in IIS,mssql,asp :D

PS: it's kind of urgent! and i have to learn as i go.

Comment: Is this a classic ASP question or is it about asp.net mvc, in which case it has the wrong tag.  There is an MVC framework for Classic ASP, it's called "ASP Extreme Evolution" but it's not exactly mainstream to say the least

Answer (score 0):

What kind of errors are you getting?

is an code error? or what?

in my experience, when you get a new windows hosting, or server, sometimes you need to activate .asp pages, since it reads only aspx by default, also, to see the code line errors you need to configure that, because normaly the errors are hidden.

to show errors on a server, you go to control panel, administrative tools, IIS, and then somewhere is the option to show errors on browser.

If you are in a hosting with plesk there is also an option to enable .asp pages and to show errors on browser.